# Is there any way to capture a newline in an html textarea with PHP/JS?

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms

So I have a textbox that people can enter into and tab, go down a line, and all that. It's like a basic notebook. I want to however retain their formatting -- as in if they click enter to go down a line, it translates into `<br />` when it is saved into my SQL table. Is there any way to do this?

I originally though I'd replace it when a string in PHP, but I realized that forms don't save that information.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use `nl2br()` to convert newlines to `<br>` tags.

I recommend doing this when you output the text to an HTML page, not when you're saving it in the database. This way you can use the data in other ways than just outputting it in HTML, and won't have to parse the HTML tags.

Comment: That worked! Thanks. Is there any way to recognize tabs?

Comment: There's nothing built in, but you could use `str_replace()`. What would you translate them to in HTML?

Comment: If you want to turn them into a table, that will require custom processing.

Comment: I would just translate to a style with padding probably. Thanks!